# Sort aggregate values in Panda

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I need to write a code that will give me a table with the most popular item and the most profitable item.
The code below, seems to be working fine, I just need to duplicate that, so that the first one is sorted by price count, and the second is sorted by price SUM.

```html
most_popular_item = Heroes_file.groupby(["Item ID", "Item Name","Price"]).agg({"Price": ['count','sum']})
                                                                                       
most_popular_item.head()


THIS WILL PRINT:


Item ID Item Name Price  
0 Splinter 1.28 4 5.12
1 Crucifer 3.26 3 9.78
2 Verdict 2.48 6 14.88
3 Phantomlight 2.49 6 14.94
4 Bloodlord's Fetish 1.70 5 8.50
```

I am using this code but I am getting the error (# Check for duplicates)

```
KeyError: 'Price count'
```

```html
most_popular_item = most_popular_item.sort_values(["Price count"], ascending=False)
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: `most_popular_item` doesn't have `Price count`. What exactly do you expect?

Comment: The table I have below is the expected output, I just need help on how to sort it so that the higher price volume is in the top

Comment: your column is named "Price" not "Price Count"

Comment: "Price" doesn't work either

Answer (score 1):

`.agg({"Price": ['count','sum']})` creates a multi-index with the columns. To sort on a multi-index you need too use a tuple like so:

```
most_popular_item = most_popular_item.sort_values(by = ('Price','count'),  ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm reading what you want correctly, but you can get a table with the largest count and sum using .nlargest()

```
target_indices = most_popular_item['count'].nlargest(1).index.values.tolist() # [2]
target_indices.extend(most_popular_item['sum'].nlargest(1).index.values.tolist()) # [2, 2]

most_popular_item[most_popular_item.index.isin(target_indices)]
```

Output:

```
   Item_ID Item_Name  Price  count    sum
2        2   Verdict   2.48      6  14.98
```

This item is both the most-popular and has the greatest sum in your group.